# How to get data from relationship objects in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-relationship

I have 2 Entity objects that i mapped in Entityframework

I have relationship between users and Messages
I want to get all messages of specific user so i load the data from users table to specific user object:

```
var user = (from u in context.Users
            where u.u_username == username
            select u).First();
```

Now, how can i get all messages of this user , i notice that i can do:

```
var messages = user.Messages;
```

But i got nothing.
Is it correct?

How can i used this syntax and to get all message of the specific user?

I used .net4
Is it possible to do

Answer (score 3):

If you want to lazy load the `Messages` of the user you can make the `Messages` property virtual.

```
public class User
{
    //other properties
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages;
}
```

Or you can eager load `Messages` using `Include` function

```
var user = (from u in context.Users.Include("Messages")
            where u.u_username == username
            select u).First();
```

Finally it maybe the case that you have not configured the `Messages` property with EF.